# How to use jQuery Autocomplete with JSON by url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to show autocomplete from url. My reference is http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

here is HTML

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

and I want to change source:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

to my url, for example (https://myapi.com/api). 
The content of the API is

```
{
  "city" : [
        {
           "city" : "Madrid",
           "id"   : "1"
        },
        { 
           "city" : "Moscow"
           "id:   : "2"
        },
        {
           "city" : "London"
           "id"   : "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I expected, I can use:

```
source: https://myapi.com/api
```

How to create it?
Thank you. it was very helpful for me

Comment: [Remote DataSource](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)

Comment: `fetch('https://myapi.com/api').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
   $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: data.city
});

})`